# Navigate and pass values to another page in PHP (HTML)

Tags: php, html, navigation, parameter-passing

I am new to PHP and here I have a problem navigating to another page by clicking in one of the rows of the table. I want also to pass the values of that row to the next page and display them there.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>List of customers</h1>
    <?php 
require_once "db_settings.php";

$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM customers";
$result = $dbi->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr> <td>".$row["id"]."</td> <td>".$row["username"]." </td> </tr>";

     }
     echo "</table>";


} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add "a" tag with GET link:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr> <td>".$row["id"]."</td> <td><a href='new_url?user_id=".$row["id"]."'>".$row["username"]." </a></td> </tr>";

 }
```

and in the new_url page use

`$user_id = $_GET['user_id']`

and now you can use the id to get the user from the database again

Comment: in the next page I need to use this right: $user_id = $_GET['user_id']

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: btw do you know how to make this list searchable?

Comment: That works thanks. However its not that safe as I can see the client id in the url.

Comment: for safety there is a lot of things to do.. what do u mean with "searchable list" i didn't get it exactly but u could use "select2" from bootstrap

Comment: I need to search in that table

Comment: use datatables provided by bootstrap too that will solve your issue